# How to plot a matrix using surf() command with a non-rectangular domain

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a matrix, Z, that I want to plot using the surf command.  I can plot it just fine using the surf command but I want part of Z to not show up in the plot.  I assume what I need to do is use the notation

```
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

where X and Y are matrices defining the (x,y) coordinate of the corresponding z value.  What I would like to know is what I put as the (x,y) coordinate for points in Z that should not be plotted, i.e. x and y should be nothing.

For example:

```
Z = 1 5 7
    2 6 0 
    3 0 0
    4 0 0

X = 1 1 1
    2 2 _
    3 _ _
    4 _ _

Y = 1 2 3
    1 2 _
    1 _ _
    1 _ _
```

What would go in the spaces? I cant put a number like 0 because all the values will just go to the origin.  I do not have to use surf() if there is a better method out there to use.

Comment: What happens if you make those zeros in Z N/A?

Comment: what do you mean by N/A?  I tried assigning it N/A and Matlab said the variable N cannot be found.  'N/A' did not work either.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry meant NaN, didn't remember exactly what the token was :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set to NaN all those values in Z that you don't want to graph. For example, if you don't want to graph the zeros of Z then

`Z(Z==0)=NaN;`

will do the trick. You don't need to do this with X and Y. If the set of Z that you don't want to graph is more complicated you should somehow obtain the Z(i,j) and set those to NaN.

Comment: thanks! I kept trying null and nill and everything I could think of.  Did not think of NaN.